# Laravel add new array key to eloquent insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add a `user_id` array key when doing an eloquent insert.  I have the following setup:

**View**

```
{!! Form::label('supervisors', 'Assign Supervisor(s)') !!}
{!! Form::select('supervisors[][supervisor_id]', $supervisors, null, ['class' => 'chosen-select', 'multiple']) !!}
```

**User Table**

```
id    first_name
12    John
```

**UserSupervisors Table**

```
id    user_id    supervisor_id
1     12         1
```

Currently the request `$request->get('supervisors')` outputs this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "supervisor_id" => "1"
  ]
]
```

However, I would like it to output this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "supervisor_id" => "1",
    "user_id" => "12"
  ]
]
```

How can I achieve this dynamically?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? I mean, for a form select I'd want an array of the `user_id => supervisor_id` kind, or vice versa.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that's what I want. Supervisors get assigned to a particular user_id so there can be more than one supervisor assigned to any one user.

Comment: How is your database set up? is this a many to many relationship? I think doing some research on laravel relationships will help you.

Comment: Yes this is a many to many relationship. I have updated my question with my table setup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this code to solve the problem:

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->user_id = 10;
 $user->supervisor_id = Input::get('supervisor_id');
 $user->save();
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't want to use this method because the user_id is dynamically generated by my controller.  The user is being added in the controller so the ID is only available within the controller. Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention I am using the Eloquent insert() method and therefore I am sending an array or arrays as above.  I need to append the user_id value to each nested array.  Therefore this solution will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

to add an item to the `Request $request`, you can use `merge()` like this :

```
$user_id = 4; //your user id
$request->merge([supervisors => ["user_id" => $user_id]]);
```

and `$request->get('supervisors')` will give you the output you need

hope that helps